# Mercurial - List out the modified lines of code in a file with line number

Tags: mercurial

I'm new to mercurial, i have a certain revision with me and i would like to switch to that particular revision and save the change-set of a particular file with line number. Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by "save the change-set"?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Save the modified lines of code to a file with line number

Comment: What about `hg diff`? That would give you the line number of the first line of each block of changes. Is that enough?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I tried that. But i would also like to have each modified line number

Comment: So you want to change the output of `hg diff` to put a line number before each line of output?

Comment: @AaronDigulla Yes, i tried hg annotate, but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a simple way to do this. Mercurial has a method where it calculates the diff between changesets and then it applies a formatter to this to print the data.

But your requirement is more complex than it looks. Imagine you have two changes in a file. In version 2, a couple of lines at the beginning have been deleted and then a line near the end has been changed.

Questions:

1. How do you plan to assign line numbers to the deleted lines? Omit them or use the original line numbers from version 1?
2. How about the lines after the deleted lines? Do you want to show the new line numbers or the original ones?
3. Which line numbers are you going to show for the changes near the end?

Of course, you could show both but that would need a lot of parsing in your head.

Some HTML-based changeset viewers use this approach: https://bitbucket.org/digulla/ts-html/commits/62fc23841ff7e7cce95eefa85244a2b821f92ba2

But I haven't see something similar for the command line since it would waste 15-20 columns of text.

Comment: Hi. I got the solution. Actually i had to output only the changes made including the added and removed lines of one particular revision without original line numbers, just the line number where the modification has been made. I got one plugin for sublime text editor which i'm using (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EasyDif). Thanks for the input